# Mismatch between widget size and @Environment value in TimelineProvider

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

Morning, everyone,

I'm developing a widget using an API that sends an array of different sizes depending on the size of the widget (small : 3 news, medium: 6 news, large: 9 news).

I have the impression that there is a problem between the `@Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family` and the timeline function (where I call the API) of TimelineProvider.

Indeed in this function the environment variable is always equal to the systemMedium size despite the "real" size of the widget.

Do you also have the same problem on your side ?
Is it a known bug from Apple ?
How can I solve this bug ?

Thanks for your help :]

Comment: Would you show your code?

Comment: Basic fetch from API then I do a switch with the three sizes of the widget. But it's always going to the systemMedium size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, my best guess is that you're not accessing the `family` property of the `TimelineProviderContext` passed into the `TimelineProvider`.

Your `TimelineProvider` should look something like:

```
struct MyProvider: TimelineProvider {
    func snapshot(with context: Context, completion: @escaping (Entry) -> ()) {
        fetchNewsArticles(for: context.family) { articles in
              // ...
              completion(...)
        }
    }
}

func fetchNewsArticles(for widgetFamily: WidgetFamily, completion: @escaping ... ) 
{
     switch family {
         case .systemSmall:
         // ...
}
```

[Apple Docs - TimelineProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineprovider)

[Apple Docs - TimelineProviderContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineprovidercontext)